# SIGSEGV when adding widget in Qt

Tags: qt

I implemented example (chapter 2) from "Mastering Qt 5" book but the code crashes when adding widget to centralWidget's layout:

```
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(&mCpuWidget)
```

I suspect that the centralWidget does not have layout, hence it crashes but I don't know how to fix that?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
mCpuWidget(this)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    SysInfo::instance().init();
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(&mCpuWidget);

}
```

Here are two more classes which might help figure out the problem. Some of you might have the book too with all of the code (hence I mentioned it).

```
CpuWidget::CpuWidget(QWidget* parent):
SysInfoWidget(parent),
mSeries (new QPieSeries (this))
{
    mSeries->setHoleSize(0.35);
    mSeries->append("CPU Load", 30.0);
    mSeries->append("CPU Free", 70.0);

    QChart* chart = chartView().chart();
    chart->addSeries(mSeries);
    chart->setTitle("CPU Average Load");
}
```

This class creates and sets layout (QVBoxLayout)

```
    SysInfoWidget::SysInfoWidget(QWidget *parent, int startDelayMs, int updateSeriesDelayMs) :
    QWidget(parent),
    mChartView(this)

{
    mRefreshTimer.setInterval(updateSeriesDelayMs);
    connect(&mRefreshTimer, &QTimer::timeout,
            this, &SysInfoWidget::updateSeries);

    QTimer::singleShot(startDelayMs,
                       [this] {mRefreshTimer.start();});

    mChartView.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    mChartView.chart()->legend()->setVisible(false);

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    layout->addWidget(&mChartView);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

Comment: Try and see the output for `qDebug() << ui->centralWidget` and for `qDebug() << ui->centralWidget->layout()` before the crash line. And overall, except maybe main window it is not a good practice to put UI widgets on stack or as a value not pointer member in class. It modifies their lifecycle not the way the Qt usually deals with. You should rather consider allocating the widget with `new MyWidget( this )` or `new MyWidget ( someParent )`. That way it is more like Qt.

Comment: @AlexanderVX There is nothing wrong to allocate the widget on the stack as a member of a class. It really depends on the scenario - do you need to dynamically delete the widget at some point before the destructor of the widget class it's a member of gets destroyed. As long as you don't forget NOT to call `delete` on that widget and also pass it as an argument to various functions using `&` (for example: `connect(&this->myWidgetOnStack, SIGNAL(...), ...)`) you are good to go.

Comment: @rbaleksandar That was not the major point but there scenarios when allocating on stack is not good. Reparent the widget, for instance. And parent works both ways as the instance for release of that child widget and also controls behavior to degree. I would not recommend to novice using widgets on stack or by value in class though it is mangeable.

Comment: Do you believe that a beginner would start dynamically re-parenting widgets? :P

Answer (score 2):

I'm the co-author of the book "[Mastering Qt 5](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/mastering-qt-5)" !

I guess your suspicion about the layout is correct:

```
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(&mCpuWidget);
```

Without any layout defined the returned item is **null** so you can't call the method layout().

If you have some errors during your learning you should refer to the final source code hosted on github here: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Qt-5

Take a look to the the file "[Mastering-Qt-5/Chapter_02/MainWindow.ui](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Qt-5/blob/master/Chapter_02/MainWindow.ui)":

```
<ui version="4.0">
  ...
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout"/>
  </widget>
 ...
</ui>
```

As you can see for this project, a *horizontalLayout* of type QHBoxLayout is defined in the *centralWidget*. You can easily edit a ".ui" file with a text editor from Qt Creator with the following steps:

1. Right-click on "MainWindow.ui" in the Project hierarchy view
2. Select "Open-With"
3. Finally "Plain text editor"

Select "Form editor" when you want to come back to the WYSIWYG editor.

As suggested in other answers, the way to do it from C++ with the following line is also correct:

```
ui->centralWidget->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout());
```

Thank you for highlighting the lack of information about the layout here. I created an [issue](https://github.com/neuronalmotion/Mastering-Qt-5/issues/3) to add an errata about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have missed something in the code you have provided you haven't actually set your central widget. By default calling `QMainWindow::centralWidget()` returns a NULL pointer. You need to first call `QMainWindow::setCentralWidget(QWidget* yourCentralWidget)` before you call it. And yes, you also need to add a layout to it if you want to use `layout()->addWidget(...)`. You can create an instance of a generic `QWidget`, set its layout, set is a central widget and then work with it.

Comment: That was what I asked the author to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your problem either by adding a layout in C++:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
SysInfo::instance().init();
ui->centralWidget->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout()); // Or any other layout class
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(&mCpuWidget);
```

Or in the UI Designer by using those buttons:
[image: Layout buttons]

Note that for the buttons to be active you need to have at least 1 widget in your central widget and then select your central widget. You can then write:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
SysInfo::instance().init();
// One way
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(&mCpuWidget);
// Another way
ui->layout->addWidget(&mCpuWidget);
```

Finally you could also move your CpuWidget to the ui file using the "Promote to..." option in the contextual menu. In this case you would not need `mCpuWidget` but you could access it using something like `ui->cpuWidget`.

For more info read the Qt Designer manual:

- [Using Layouts in Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)
- [Using Custom Widgets with Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html)

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I will take my time and digest all of this. For now, I added ui->centralWidget->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout()); and it fixed the problem. I tried doing the fix in UI Designer but I  must have done something wrong as I could not get it to work. I was confused by what is done in the SysInfoWidget class (setting the layout using QVBoxLayout). I though this should have been done in MainWindow but I guess that layout applied only to SysInfoWidget.. I still needed different one in the MainWindow.